System.InvalidOperationException: 'No data exists for the row/column.'
TABLE NAME: tblStocks
COLUMN NAME: Item_Code
SAMPLE BELOW:

Item_Code
110001
220001
110002
220001
110003

CODE:
sql = "SELECT LAST(Item_Code) as @item_code FROM tblStocks where
item_code LIKE '11%'"
        
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        
txtAvailable.Text = dr("@item_code").ToString

NEED TO DISPLAY THE LATEST Item Code using SQL and display it on TextBox that starts with "11"

I am not sure, which SQL-dialect supports LAST. Is it something from Visual Basic?

please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms  so that we can point you in the right direction

MSAccess wildcard is *, not %

Yes I'm using vb.net

still no valuee

@Sergey: The following may be of interest: First, Last Functions

The following may be of interest: Access wildcard character reference

SELECT TOP 1 Item_Code ... WHERE Item_code LIKE '11*' ORDER BY Item_Code DESC.

What is the data type of the column "Item_Code"? Just to be sure.

@Andrew, only in Access frontend UI is the wildcard, *. In programmatic backend connection (i.e., ODBC, OleDB), the Access wildcard is %. This may be an undocumented fact from lessons learned!

As the query returns a single value, you can use ExecuteScalar.
You can quickly give it a try in a new project, just to experiment, with something like this (there is a TextBox named "txtAvailable"):
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Const CONNSTR As String = "your connection string here"

    Function GetAvailable() As String
        Dim available = ""

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(CONNSTR)
            Dim sql = "SELECT LAST(Item_Code)
                        FROM tblStocks
                        HAVING Item_Code LIKE '11%'
                        ORDER BY LAST(Item_Code)"

            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
                conn.Open()
                Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

                If result IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(result) Then
                    available = CStr(result)
                End If

            End Using

        End Using

        Return available

    End Function

    Sub ShowAvailable()
        txtAvailable.Text = GetAvailable()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ShowAvailable()

    End Sub

End Class

Avoid using non-alphanumeric characters, for example "@", for things like aliases. Keep it simple. There isn't a need for an alias with ExecuteScalar.
You must use an ORDER BY if you want a database query to give consistently ordered results.
In that example, if ExecuteScalar returned Nothing then there was no value returned from the query, so you might want to act on that.
If there is no value returned from the query but you are sure you using the exact correct column name, then perhaps it is using the wrong database file. Check the connection string again.
Always use the Using construct for database connections so that they are properly disposed of immediately after use—it's all designed to work properly that way.
I wonder if what you want can be expressed more simply as:
Dim sql = "SELECT MAX(Item_Code) FROM tblStocks WHERE Item_Code LIKE '11%'"

Incidentally, the convention in databases is to not prefix table names with something like "tbl".

Shouldn't it be LIKE '11%' instead of LIKE '11*' ? because * is for DAO and this ADO.net.

It might get the data, but runs on the UI

@djv You're free to write an answer running on a different thread ;)

@ShahramAlemzadeh Thanks, I had a chance to actually test it today and you are of course correct, so I made the appropriate adjustments in my answer.

First, the answer by Andrew Morton is absolutely correct about using: ORDER BY, .ExecuteScalar and Using Blocks.
But it will fail due to using * instead of %.
In ADO, * treated as a normal character and LIKE '11*' returns single item 11*, ... and not 1110, 11abc, ...
Also ORDER BY should be applied to the aggregate column (LAST).
Using con As New OleDbConnection(".. connection string ...")
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LAST([Item_Code]) FROM tblStocks HAVING [Item_Code] LIKE '11%' ORDER BY LAST([Item_Code])"
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim item_code = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        If Not IsDBNull(item_code) Then
            txtAvailable.Text = item_code.ToString
        End If
    End Using
    con.Close()
End Using


Queries with LIKE running inside the Access frontend via the Office app (MSAccess.exe) uses the * wildcard. But LIKE  queries run in any backend connection to .accdb uses the % wildcard. Access users should consider ALIKE which always uses the ANSI wildcard, %.
